# Save zeros before digits in numeric field

Tags: delphi

In an old application, I have a table (Paradox DB) that contains a numeric "number" field.

The user can enter the "number" in two ways:

Example:
1- **123**
or
2- **000123**

I have not yet found the trick to record a recording starting with zeros.
How to save zeros in DB as: **000123** please?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use a text field instead. You cannot save the leading zeroes otherwise or you need to store the format elsewhere in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store leading zeros in a numeric column. If you need to retain leading zeros then you must use a text column, or perhaps a separate column to contain the number of leading zeros.

Comment: frankly, I don't know about Paradox, but in DBF the "numeric" fields we actually text fields, which was exactly what let them keep zeroes.
Those are implementation details though, thus unreliable IMHO

Answer (score 2):

This isn't to do with storage, it is to do with display. If the database is that old the value is probably stored internally as two bytes, and so 'leading zeros' is meaningless in terms of storage. The alternatives are to store data as a string (which happens to contain numeric digits) or format the (text) display using standard formatting routines.